# Golang: http2 message header & Json body split into 2 or 3 packets

Tags: go, http2

[image]
[image]
[image]

We found a weird problem in our test, when sending a http2 packets, even the total data is not very big, we found the single packet will be splitted into 2 or 3 packets, 1 with header and 1 or 2 packet with Json data. Could any know which setting could solve this problem to put them in one single packet when size allowed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is mostly out of your control, and why does it matter? Your data will still arrive as expected, how many TCP packets it's in really has no impact.

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for your reply, we're in a very high load test, the more TCP packets will impact the performance test result, so we need to put them in one single packet if we could.

Comment: already found it in http2/transport.go, Golang will send header and body separately.

Comment: If you need such fine control, you may want to use grpc, it has its own http2 implementation.